# PHP complex form

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to figure out how one would construct an HTML form that is complex. let me explain below .

For example in the form i have a drop down menu for electronic devices if choose mobile then serial number, model name, make year etc.. will ask with text box(which can be done easily with angular)
then a radio button and ask is sim card  included ? YES OR NO, if yes then sim card number sim expiration etc ...
Same like other devices like laptops has Hard Disk included or not ?

How can i build some kind of tree architecture form with php ?

Comment: Please show examples of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this with javascript... php requires page refresh. if you know ajax that would be a better option than php for such a thing

Comment: You are right, yes i will do the front end part with angularjs but i want solution about the php in back-end